# How to check updates installed?

Tags: updates

Using ubuntu 16, updates settings on check every day + download and install automatically.  Please, could you tell me how to check if the updates have been installed? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use two methods here to check if you have any updates pending which would suggest updates were not install and need to be.

Steps:

1. from dash type **software updater** and select it
2. from terminal run `sudo apt update`

In the **first** one it would check and tell you if any updates are required.

In the **second** one it will check to see if your **repositories** are up to date and tell you if any **packages** needs updating, then if so you may update using:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

To see the history of your updates:

```
less /var/log/apt/history.log
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You don't answer to my ask. I wish a check of what updates installed, not to do.

Comment: please see updated answer.